# Sudden change in central potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I was wondering what would happen to the path of a mass in a central force $F=-K/r^2$ if $K$ is suddenly reduced by a factor 2. Let's say the initial orbit is circular.

Would the planet stay in a circular orbit, only at twice the distance, or twice as fast?

Comment: What is a central force? I would expect your expression to be a combination of Newton's 2nd law with the formula for centripetal acceleration, but I am not used to seeing the negative sign here.

Comment: Well, did you try to work out an example? What stops you from reaching a conclusion?

Comment: This is a very specific exercise style problem (initial circular orbit and force magnitude is halved) rather than a conceptual question. In your long comment you state both conceptual and calculational assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the halving of the central force can not change the tangential velocity, you can not have higher speed, and also not just a new circular path, so you would have an ellipse where the path will return to the starting place or a hyperbola, you should calculate the escape velocity, for the half force, I don't have the time for it right now. In the meantime I did the math. The body will go away - escape to infinity- when you half the force.